# .Net PowerPoint automation - edit/delete text with Hyperlink from SmartArt

Tags: .net, hyperlink, powerpoint, office-automation

How can I access Hyperlink that is located in shape inside SmartArt object of PowerPoint slide?

This is code with which I can read hyperlink text:

```
      For Each s As PowerPoint.Slide In oPres.Slides
         For Each sh As PowerPoint.Shape In s.Shapes
            Select Case sh.Type
                Case MsoShapeType.msoSmartArt
                    For Each san As SmartArtNode In sh.SmartArt.Nodes
                        If san.TextFrame2.HasText Then
                            Debug.WriteLine(san.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text)
                        End If
                    Next
            End Select
        Next
     Next
```

But how to access link, and change it, remove, etc?

Comment: Oh my, dat nesting... But apart from that, what does the program output when there's a link in the shape's text?

Comment: For example, when I put text: Test, and link it with: http://www.test.com, with this code I get output: 'Test', means only plain text.

Comment: All I can find is some code similar to yours to *add* hyperlinks, not sure if it [helps](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?10167-Solved-Hyperlink-TEXT-not-TextFrame-PPT-help!!), but might be a push in the right direction.

Comment: TextFrame object do have ActionSettings property, and on other objects (all BUT SmartArt) I do it that way, or similar.
But SmartArtNode has only this TextFrame2, which unfortunately don't have it... Thanks Melvin for trying!